# Recorrer QuerySet en Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo un archivo processors.py donde genero un procesador de contexto para cargar datos estáticos en la plantilla base de mi proyecto.
Tengo publicaciones y quiero generar como una especie de archivo en un aside, donde se pueda acceder a través de un link, a los posts que se crearon en el mes de agosto de 2022 (por ejemplo) y eso me llevará a una página donde veré todo el listado de posts. Para armar esa lista, de este especie de archivo, hago lo siguiente en el archivo processors.py:

```html
def ctx_dic_history(request):
    ctx_history = {}
    ctx_history['dates'] = Post.objects.dates('created','month').distinct()
    return ctx_history
```

Si en el aside coloco `{{ dates }}` me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
<QuerySet [datetime.date(2022, 7, 1), datetime.date(2022, 8, 1), datetime.date(2022, 9, 1), datetime.date(2022, 10, 1)]>
```

Ahora quiero recorrer ese queryset, pero no logro obtener lo que necesito: quiero primero, que esten ordenados descendentemente, es decir, el mes más reciente encima de todo. Segundo quiero acceder al mes y el año, es decir que aparezca algo como "Agosto de 2022"

```html
{% for item in dates %}
   <a href="">Probando</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Con eso logro iterar sobre los items que me trae ese queryset, pero no se cómo acceder a la fecha en cuestión de cada item del queryset. Si me pueden dar una mano se los agradecería de antemano. Si logro hacerlo funcionar, sin dudar publicaré la respuesta que funcionó para mi. Muchas Gracias !!!

Comment: item.created | date:"%B  %Y"

Comment: No funciona, es lo primero que se me ocurrió. Poner item.created. No se si eso ocurre desde el momento en que construyo la variable "dates"

Comment: que tipo de columna es tu campo date?

Comment: <QuerySet [datetime.date(2022, 7, 1), datetime.date(2022, 8, 1), datetime.date(2022, 9, 1), datetime.date(2022, 10, 1)]> tipo datetime.date

Comment: deberia formatearse que version de django estas utilizando? en todo caso puedes hacer un for antes de enviar al template y utilizar un `strftime("formato")`  para modificar el registro date a tu gusto...

Answer (score 1):

> quiero primero, que esten ordenados descendentemente

Si consultas la documentación de Django, la ordenación descendente se puede hacer especificando el tercer parámetro (order='DESC').
[Querysets:Dates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#dates)

> quiero acceder al mes y el año, es decir que aparezca algo como "Agosto de 2022"

En este caso, si te fijas, los elementos del Queryset son del tipo "datetime.date". Te invito a ver la [Documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime), donde hay una función (strftime) con la que puedes convertir la fecha al formato que quieras (tienes los ejemplos [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)):

```
import datetime
my_date = datetime.date.today()
print( my_date.strftime("%B of %Y") )  --> 'November of 2022'
```

En tu caso, "my_date" sería el **item** de tu bucle *for*.
Para acceder a día, mes, año, tienes el atributo **day**, **month** y **year**, entre otros.

---**Edit 4/11/22:**

Para el formato de salida, tienes también la opción de [filtrado](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#filter) que ofrecen las templates de Django. Para el caso de las fechas, puedes echar un vistazo a ver si te sirve [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7749024).

Comment: Disculpa, se me coló un texto que no era al inicio. La primera parte, corresponde a tu pregunta ""quiero primero, que esten ordenados descendentemente"". Un saludo.

Comment: Dale [edit] a tu respuesta y elimina la parte que no corresponde a la pregunta para no crear confusión.

Comment: si hago {{ item.month|date:"F" }} no funciona osea la unica forma que me muestre los registros es haciendo {{ item.month }} {{ item.year }} por separado...

Comment: Leyendo en los docs, parece que el filtro **date** es válido solo para objetos de la clase **datetime.datetime**, y no para **datetime.date** como es este caso. Las opciones que tienes entonces es, o lo que comenta @Bryro de ponerlo en el backend antes de devolver el objeto, ejecutando la función **strftime**, que me parece que será lo más sencillo; o también tienes la opción de [crear tu propio filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) (que para este caso no merece la pena, pero está bien que sepas de esta posibilidad para futuros casos).

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la respuesta. Ahora logre ordenar de forma descendente, pero todavia no he logrado poner los nombres de los meses
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en la vista estoy recorriendo el queryset de esta forma:

```
{% for item in dates %}
    <li>
       <a href={% url 'dates' %}>{{ item.month }} de {{ item.year }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Si hago `{{ item.strftime("%B of %Y") }}` no funciona a pesar que el item es una fecha.