# ¿Cómo obtener la fecha en formato aaaa/mm/dd, mediante una consulta en Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Quiero obtener las fecha de una tabla guardada en mi base de datos *MySQL*. La queryset que utilizo es:

```
persona.objects.only('fecha_nacimiento')
```

Al guardar eso en una lista y mostrarlo en el *HTML* obtengo las fecha pero de la siguiente manera: **Nov. 16, 2022**.
Ya corroboré que en mi base de datos se esté guardando como tipo `date` y es ahí donde puedo observar la fecha en formato *aaaa/mm/mm*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el [filtro `date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date) de Django para formatear las fechas como quieras.

De modo que si tienes en tu HTML `{{ fecha_nacimiento }}` esto pasaría a ser `{{ fecha_nacimiento|date:"Y/m/d" }}`.

Esto lo hará solo para la plantilla HTML que modifiques con `date`. Si no, se puede hacer de forma global [modificando DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-DATE_FORMAT) en los ajustes de Django.

Comment: Como complemento: dependerá también de si el objeto que interpreta python al acceder a ese elemento es tipo Date o Datetime. Si es de dipo Date, el filtro no funcionará. Puedes echar un vistazo [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/566067/198957), que estuvimos tratando hace poco algo parecido.

Comment: @Radoslav ¿No funciona con Date pero sí con Datetime? :O

Comment: Eso es. Si buscas en la documentacion de Django del **filter**, al final del apartado si mal no recuerdo, pone que solo admite **Datetime**. No se si explicaba mucho el por qué, pero mi explicación es que la clase **Datetime** tiene bastante más información que **Date**, y por tanto, más manipulable.